# How to addlines of various pen styles?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, teechart

I have a TChart and want to draw horizontal lines as markers. That far, that easy. These lines shall have different pens, like widths and colors. What ever I try, I end up with my horizontal lines all looking the same!

This is what I tried:

```
Linien:=TDrawLineTool.Create(Self); // creates the drawtool <br>
CustomChart.Tools.Add(Linien);<br>
Linien.Pen.Width:=20;<br>
Linien.Lines.AddLine(0,d,high(Trades_),d); // first line<br>

Linien.Pen.Width:=40;<br>
Linien.Lines.AddLine(0,d2,high(Trades_),d2); // another line<br>
```

=> ends up with both being 40 (or red or whatever).

How can I draw every line in its own style? Must I create more Linien, if yes: how to appostrophe them? Or must every line be its own drawing tool (creating lots of them?)

Comment: thank you for this link. But NO, my question is different. I do not want to color a point / bar of a series.<br> It is about "DrawLineTool" which is added to an axis directly.

Answer (score 1):

`TDrawLineTool` holds collection of lines - but stores only their coordinates, not attributes for every line.

From help:

> Description The Pen property refers to the TDrawLineTool owner of
>   every line. All Lines share the same Pen object.

So yes, you have to create separate TDrawLineTool for every line style/width.